# Composition of Morse function with diffeomorphism isotopic to identity is a morse function

Tags: differential-geometry, morse-theory

Suppose I have a Morse function $f$ on a compact smooth manifold $M$, potentially with boundary, and that $h$ is an automorphism of $M$ isotopic to the identity automorphism. Then is $f\circ h$ a Morse function?

It seems clear to me that critical points of $f$ will under $h^{-1}$ be mapped to critical points of $f\circ h$ and that these points will still be locally quadratic (that is, non-degenerate.) But that these should be the only critical points is slightly mysterious to me.

Comment: The title says "diffeomorphism" but your question says "automorphism". I assume by "automorphism" you mean "self-diffeomorphism".

Comment: Precisely. This is just an artifact of poor editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $h$ is a diffemorphism, then $dh$ is everywhere nonsingular. Because 
$$
d(f \circ h)  = df \circ dh
$$
(depending on notation, etc. --- we're talking about the chain rule here), we have $d(f\circ h)(P)(v)$ is zero exactly when $df(Q)(w)$ is zero (where $Q = h(P)$ for some nonzero $w$, because $dh(P)(v)$ is never zero for any nonzero $v$, because $h$ is a diffeomorphism.

The one weird thing about this question is that "isotopic to the identity" is completely irrelevant; is there a part "b" or "c" that might use that assumption?

Comment: Yes, this is a small part to a problem I'm working on that for one reason or another just wasn't clicking with me. Thank you for the straightforward answer.

Comment: So why, 15 months later, did you decide to withdraw the check-mark for my answer? I don't really care about the points, but...it seems like an odd choice.